# Accepting multiple parameters in MVC 4 Web API controller and mapping to custom methods

Tags: vb.net, web-services, rest, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to implement a Web API project that exposes some models. However, the way the model is retrieved isn't very RESTful.

1.
Instead of having just one ID, it has a combination of 4 different ones to populate the model data by running a stored proc on the server.

```
Dim balance as New BalanceSheet(uid, mid, eid, fid)
```

The snippet above will use `uid`, `mid`, `eid`, `fid` to retrieve the correct record from the database.

How would I implement this in the controller so that `/api/Balance?uid=1&mid=2&eid=3&fid=4` maps to `GetBalance(ByVal uid As Integer, ByVal mid As Integer, ByVal eid As Integer, ByVal fid As Integer)`

2.
Additionallly, I want to be able to filter specific members of BalanceSheet model or get some preprocessed object return like so:
`/api/Balance/FundCredit?uid=1&mid=2&eid=3&fid=4` maps to `GetFundcredit(ByVal uid As Integer, ByVal mid As Integer, ByVal eid As Integer, ByVal fid As Integer)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it following this article: [REST vs. RPC in ASP.NET Web API](http://encosia.com/rest-vs-rpc-in-asp-net-web-api-who-cares-it-does-both/).

I was actually trying to combine two different paradigms it seems - RPC and REST. I initially thought (wrongly) that the `api/{controller}/{action}/{id}` could only map to functions that return an `ActionResult` type.

Here's my routing rules:

```
        routes.MapHttpRoute( _
            name:="RPCApi", _
            routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{action}"
        )

        routes.MapHttpRoute( _
            name:="RESTApi", _
            routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}", _
            defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional} _
        )
```

Which map `api/balance/?uid=1&mid=2&eid=3&fid=4` and `api/balance/fundcredit?uid=1&mid=2&eid=3&fid=4` to these two functions respectively:

```
      Public Function GetBalance(ByVal uid As Integer, ByVal mid As Integer, ByVal eid As Integer, ByVal fid As Integer)
        Try
            Dim balance As New BalanceSheet(uid, mid, eid, fid)

            Return balance
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Function FundCredit(ByVal uid As Integer, ByVal mid As Integer, ByVal eid As Integer, ByVal fid As Integer)
        Dim balance As New BalanceSheet(uid, mid, eid, fid)

        Return balance.FundCredit
    End Function
```

Comment: Found an arguably "safer" technique that explicitly maps actions and methods together, here: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/08/29/how-a-method-becomes-an-action.aspx